# Why shouldn't I use SharePoint for source control?

Tags: sharepoint, version-control

I just started working at a company that doesn't have any kind of source control.  I brought up that we might need to get some sort of source control going and one of my co-workers suggested that we use SharePoint.  I think he likes the idea because we already use sharepoint he is a big SharePoint guy.

I came up with some reasons as to why we shouldn't do this.

- SharePoint isn't designed to be a source control tool for code.
- There are better (and still free) tools for the job
- You can't do automated deploys with sharepoint (to my knowledge)
- It won't integrate with any IDEs (to my knowledge)

Is there anything else I should include when i'm pleading my case?

Comment: Wow - no source control and you should already have one foot out of the door! If SharePoint is going to be used then run like the wind! ;) http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html

Comment: Parts of TFS are SharePoint - you might be able to say that you will be using SharePoint but need TFS to handle the integration between Visual Studio and SharePoint.

Comment: When we have document library of sharepoint and work with Microsoft Word and compares two versions of same document we guess that sharepoint can do that but hasn't all features that a programmer need but I Think (  after ten year work with sharepoint and programming )   we can use it as Web Access to our source code for review or comment or note opinions without compile. (because a programmer in several times need to review and comment on archive libraries)  do you agree with me

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Why using sharepoint as a sorce control is stupid idea:

1. Performance of sharepoint is much worse than any Source Control Tools for example Team Foundation Server or SVN
2. Sharepint doesn't allow to compare different historical versions of the same file
3. SharePoint dosen't allow for branching, merging and labeling.
4. Sharepoint doesn't link changes in set of files as a one change (this is very helpful if you want to track the changes)
5. As far as I know SP doesn't allow to have different versions of whole project in the same time.
6. SharePoint dosen't have customized gui to manage source control code.
7. Sharepoint doesn't allow to link requirements with code changes. For example TFS links work items with check ins. This is also very helpful if you want to track your business requirements and code changes.

Comment: +1 for stupid. (Sorry nothing personal. Just anything with sharepoint and stupid gets +1)

Answer (score 5):

Licensing Costs... You can get many many many tools that cost much less (even if they turn up their noses at free tools) for the same cost as SP.

Also, no branching and/or merging.

Using SP for source control is like living in a factory because it's got 4 walls and a roof. Totally ignores functionality and intent.

Comment: @Abe no branching and merging would be very difficult working. Consider other tools, as SP is not suited for several files source control, just file by file source control.

Answer (score 3):

Another problem with SP, if there are versions being removed by someone, SharePoint doesn't keep the full history on who removed them (as far as I know).

The sad thing is a lot people, including our company, don't have the concept of revision control. The point is they need to be educated on how important it is to have a configuration management or revision control process.

Answer (score 1):

Sharepoint is not a source control tool.  There are many dozens of free and commercial tools that are designed for exactly this problem.  Sharepoint is not one of them.

I realize these are points you've already stated in your post.  I think that should be the end of the argument.  If you have to go any further in defending against this horribly bad idea, I can't imagine what the rest of their processes are like.

Comment: Does this really deserve aggressive downvoting?  Seems to me like stating "your case should already be strong enough" is, if not the most helpful answer, at least a valid one.

Answer (score 1):

Cost is probably not an issue - SP Foundation is free. Still, not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

SP Doesn't integrate with the IDE, so CheckIN,CheckOut will be manual.

- By the way GIT doesn't integrate with the majority of IDE's and it is still one good SC tool.

SP Doesn't have a way to create branch's (only by manually creating a new folder and manually telling the devs to use the new Branch). (this will be pretty hard depending on the number of devs)

SP treats every change as independent of the rest, so no way to look at changes in a timeline. This is like this because SP source is not made for "project" source control, its made for "file" source control.

- This is a downsize.

SP places all files on database using varbinary(max) this increase the Sharepoint Database file size, and it actually takes a little more space than what it would if it was on disk. (I'm not saying BLOB is evil, but when used a lot it makes DB maintenance HELL)

But overall the only good reason i can think off is that it doesn't integrate with the IDE, so you will have a lot of work to use it. Imagine several developers copying all of their files to a sharepoint Library, that would slow them down.

And Last its not fast enough devs won't like it (even more because of the added steps).

Answer (score 0):

Using SharePoint as source version control:

**Cons**:
 - no support for de-duplication, every version is a folder is a full
   copy.
 - Unable to do full file set labeling for rollbacks - for example if
   you want to revert your product as a whole to specific point in time.
 - Files are not hashed, hashing is a modern technique for performance -
   for example git or mercurial only compare the hash values to
   determine if the file are identical which is very fast.

**Pros** 
using sharepoint as version control if yo already have the licensing.

- it provides linear versioning for binaries, sometimes that's all what
  you want.  for example if you want to version a macro attached to a
  MS doc or excel.
- Good for binaries with no dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Surely though, a SharePoint library folder storing text files is preferable for using code within SharePoint. You wouldn't use bitbucket or confluence etc. for code that pulls in to a content editor webpart.

Comment: While your resurrecting a 12 year old post, inactive for 3 years, I think the topic was using a source control system, not how to host the files that will be used in SharePoint customization.